# Is it possible to upload MP3s to Audible's Iphone app?

Tags: audio

I have some MP3 files that I would like to add to my Audible library. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it doesn't support MP3s. It only supports .m4b or .aa